# python - issue with len in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list

```
listA = ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"]
```

I have this code and it should be working

```
a = 0
for nb in listA:
    if a == 0:
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    a += 1
    if len(listA[nb]) == 2:
        print("*   " + nb + "   *").center(20)
    elif len(listA[nb]) == 1:
        print("*   " + nb + "    *").center(20)
    else:
        print("* " + nb + " *")
    if a == len(listA):
        listA[-1]
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    #print(a)
```

Yet, I'm having this error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Looking at it, I've changed it the nb to an integer and it works. Still, when I'm doing `len(listA[1])`, I have 5.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: In your for loop `nb` is a string so you can't do `listA[nb]`

Comment: `listA[1] == 'World' and len('World') == 5`, what did you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nb` is the `string` in your `listA`. So `listA[nb]` is invalid, you can just use `nb`.

```
a = 0
for nb in listA:
    if a == 0:
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    a += 1
    if len(nb) == 2:
        print("*   " + nb + "   *").center(20)
    elif len(nb) == 1:
        print("*   " + nb + "    *").center(20)
    else:
        print("* " + nb + " *")
    if a == len(listA):
        listA[-1]
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    #print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the other 2 answers, you have a line `listA[-1]`.

I don't know what you expect it to do, but it does nothing. It just returns the last element in `listA`.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is not with len, but with **listA[nb]**. You iterate over the list, so **nb** is a string. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, to get the length of the list item simply do **len(nb)**.

Answer (score 1):

`for nb in listA` will iterate over every element of your listA, so `nb` is always the type of the "current" element.
I'm not completely sure what you want to do but if you want to know/use the index of the elements in `listA` you could use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
listA = ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"]
for idx, nb in enumerate(listA):
    if idx == 0:
        print("*"*10).center(20)
    if len(listA[idx]) == 2:
        print("*   " + nb + "   *").center(20)
    elif len(listA[idx]) == 1:
        print("*   " + nb + "    *").center(20)
    else:
        print("* " + nb + " *")
    if idx == len(listA):
        # listA[-1] # this does nothing at all, just returns the last element of the list
        print("*"*10).center(20)
```